# Run an exe file from code

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

How do I run an exe file from the Main method of a console application.

IDE: Visual Studio 2013
Target Framework: 4.5.1

Because i'm trying this one out but I can't find the System.Diagnostics namespace when I tried to add a reference: [Process Tutorial](https://www.dotnetperls.com/process)

Comment: System.Diagnostics is included by default. You just need to add a using (e.g. `using System.Diagnostics`)

Comment: Can you right-click the project and select "properties" and tell us what the "target framework" says?

Comment: @john please write your comment as an answer and i will mark it as an answer. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.Diagnostics is included by default.

You just need to add a using (e.g. `using System.Diagnostics;`) or you can declare the variable as `System.Diagnostics.Process process;`

code:

```
string exeFileAndLocation = @"C:\myConsoleApplication.exe";
string arguments = "sampleArgument";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(exeFileAndLocation, arguments);
```